# Jquery calculation issue (returning NaN)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in which certain calculations are happening as per the dropdown selected. Everything is working fine except that when i select a value from dropdown price/unit field has to be filled by calculating (total1/qty) which is returning NaN. Pls help on this? My markup is below:

```
 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Dept</title>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>

 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
 $(window).load(function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").on('change',function () {
    var dept_number = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');

 $(this).closest('table').find('.deptip').val(dept_number);
 $(this).closest('table').find('.priceip').val(price);
 $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val(price * $(this).closest('table').find('.total').data('value'));
  $(this).closest('table').find('.price_unit').val($(this).closest('table').find('.total1').data('value') / $(this).closest('table').find('.qty').data('value'));

  });
  });
  });//]]> 




 </script>

 </head>

  <body>
  <div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
  <table border="1"><tr>
   <td><select id="category0">
   <option value="1" data-price="10">USD</option>
   <option value="2" data-price="20">INR</option>
   <option value="3" data-price="30">AUD</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><label>Dept. num:</label>
     <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class--></td>
     <td><label>Price:</label>
     <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too--></td>
     <td><label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total" value="50"/></td>
     <td><label>Qty:</label><input type="text" class="qty" value="5"/></td>
     <td><label>Total1:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total1"/></td>
    <td><label>Price/Unit:</label><input type="text" readonly class="price_unit" /></td>


  </tr></table>
  </div>

  <div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
  <table border="1"><tr>
  <td><select id="category1">
   <option value="1" data-price="10">USD</option>
   <option value="2" data-price="20">INR</option>
   <option value="3" data-price="30">AUD</option>
   </select></td>
    <td><label>Dept. num:</label>
    <input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class--></td>
     <td><label>Price:</label>
     <input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too--></td>
     <td><label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total" value="50"/></td>
       <td><label>Qty:</label><input type="text" class="qty" value="5" /></td>
      <td><label>Total1:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total1"/></td>
      <td><label>Price/Unit:</label><input type="text" readonly class="price_unit"/></td>

   </tr></table>
  </div>

  <div class="base"> <!--Keep each group in base container-->
  <table border="1"><tr>
   <td><select id="category2">
   <option value="1" data-price="10">USD</option>
   <option value="2" data-price="20">INR</option>
   <option value="3" data-price="30">AUD</option>
</select></td>
<td><label>Dept. num:</label>
<input type="text" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/><!--give them a class--></td>
<td><label>Price:</label>
<input type="text" class="priceip" id="price-input"/> <!--a class here too--></td>
<td><label>Total:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total" value="50"/></td>
    <td><label>Qty:</label><input type="text" class="qty" value="5" /></td>
<td><label>Total1:</label><input data-value="50" type="text" readonly class="total1"/></td>
    <td><label>Price/Unit:</label><input type="text" readonly class="price_unit"/></td>


 </tr></table>
  </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Too much repeated code and not enough useful variable names makes me go *ugh* - and not want to look further. In any case, if the result is NaN then one (or more) of the inputs results in NaN when used in a numeric context - maybe one of the `val` or `data` calls returned undefined?

Comment: The data is coming in a while loop, so i copied the html output. Anyways thanx for the info.

Comment: He was probably talking about your JS. You need to use variables for things you will access more than once. It is much, much easier to read, and it is way faster as right now the browser must recalculate every selector everytime you use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.qty` input has a `value` and you are trying to get its `data-value`

Try this

```
$("select").on('change', function () {
    var dept_number = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    $(this).closest('table').find('.deptip').val(dept_number);
    $(this).closest('table').find('.priceip').val(price);
    $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val(price * $(this).closest('table').find('.total').data('value'));
    $(this).closest('table').find('.price_unit').val($(this).closest('table').find('.total1').data('value') / $(this).closest('table').find('.qty').val());

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zu6uvzxv/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string var to float or int using parseInt or parseFloat

```
 $(this).closest('table').find('.price_unit').val(parseInt($(this).closest('table').find('.total1').attr('value')) / parseInt($(this).closest('table').find('.qty').attr('value')));
```

Comment: No still iam getting NaN.

Comment: Then either total1 or qty is not returned correctly. You will need to check